# Update prevention when dropping version support

Tags: shopware, shopware6

We are planning to drop support for all SW versions below 6.4.6.0 in an upcoming major plugin version.
If we configure the supported versions in the Shopware Account correctly, will

1. the shop owners with unsupported versions be blocked from updating?
2. the shop owners be able to update to the newest supported version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, shops with a Shopware version that doesn't match the version requirements of the plugin update will not get a notification about it and won't be able to update through the extension module.
2. Shop owners will be able to update the aforementioned plugin once they update their shop to a version that matches the version requirements of the plugin update.

In short: You can't have both. Either you deny shops with non-matching Shopware versions the update or you allow them to update to the latest version, but then you can't have the Shopware version restriction.